# Возможно ли мигрировать авторизацию с yii2 PHP на Spring Security?

Tags: php, java, laravel, spring, yii

Есть админка с REST API на Yii2 (PHP), и мобильное приложение, в котором пользователи авторизуются по email и через социальные сети типа вк.
Есть планы переноса админки и API на Spring (Java).

Вопрос, как в этом случае быть с авторизацией? Имеется ввиду совместимость токенов, которые были сгенерированы Yii и как это переварит Spring Security.

Прощу прощения за общие формулировки, буду признателен за пояснения))

Answer (score 0):

> Имеется ввиду совместимость токенов, которые были сгенерированы Yii и
>   как это переварит Spring Security.

Если речь идёт о самом web приложении, то токен уникален и имеет ограниченное время жизни. Поэтому даже в одном и том же приложении 2 токена несовместимы между собой. Генерируете токены штатными средствами соответствующего фреймворка и всё.

Если авторизация через соцсети, то это уже, как минимум на половину не Ваша забота, т.к. необходимые данные Вам должна отдавать соответствующая соцсеть.